# Find the largest sum of any contiguous subarray of the array

Tags: code-golf, array, subsequence

Let's say you are given an integer array. Create a function to determine the largest sum of any array's adjacent subarrays. For instance, the contiguous subarray with the largest sum is `[4, -1, 2, 1]` in the array `[-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4]`.

You can employ a variant of Kadane's algorithm to resolve this issue. The steps are as follows:

1. Set `max_so_far` and `max_ending_here`, two variables, to the first array element.
2. From the second element all the way to the end, traverse the array.
3. Update the `max_ending_here` variable for each element by either adding the current element to it or setting it to the current element if it is larger than the sum of the previous elements.
4. If the `max_ending_here` variable is larger than the `max_so_far` variable, update it.
5. The `max_so_far` variable holds the largest sum of any contiguous subarray after traversing the entire array.

The steps are optional to perform if you may like. The best one which wins is the shortest in length!

## Leaderboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=257808,OVERRIDE_USER=116868;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px} /* font fix */ body {font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;} /* #language-list x-pos fix */ #answer-list {margin-right: 200px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: ight! Thanks so much!

Comment: Is this [tag:restricted-complexity] or can we brute force it? Brute force will be much shorter than the efficient algorithm in most languages

Comment: Also, welcome to Code Golf and nice first challenge! You might want to check out [the default I/O methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) and allow full programs as well as functions.

Comment: @mousetail you are given the option to use brute force, I just recommended the algorithm to be used. You can use brute forcing.

Comment: thanks so much for motivating me @TheThonnu it helps!

Comment: Yea nobody is going to use the algorithm you describe, it's way to long to be competetive

Comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/23971/91213

Comment: @mousetail thanks so much again for explaining the etymology here. I will keep it in mind!

Comment: This question has already been asked many times. Here are two of them. https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3059/find-largest-sum-of-subsequence/46972 https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/138697/maximum-sub-array I am confident there are many more.

Comment: @chunes it is asking for standard user-defined input while I am asking for a pre-defined formatted array as a requirement,

Comment: Is empty array an subarray?

Answer (score 5):

## Vyxal `G`, 3 bytes

```
ÞSṠ
```

This is my first Vyxal answer but I'm already outgolfing TheThonnu lol

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJHIiwiIiwiw55T4bmgIiwiIiwiWy0yLCAxLCAtMywgNCwgLTEsIDIsIDEsIC01LCA0XSJd)

```
ÞSṠ
ÞS  : Sublists
  Ṡ : Vectorized sum (sum each)
    : -G: Max
```

Comment: slay! The shortest answer possible

Comment: Nice! I didn't check for that command!

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 69 bytes

```python
lambda x:max(sum(x[a:b])for a in range(len(x))for b in range(len(x)))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3XXMSc5NSEhUqrHITKzSKS3M1KqITrZJiNdPyixQSFTLzFIoS89JTNXJS8zQqNMGiSRiimlDDVAuKMvNKNNI0og11jHSMdXSNdQxiNTW54MK6hrEwxQsWQGgA)

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 74 bytes

Outputs the list

```python
lambda x:max((x[a:b]for a in range(len(x))for b in range(len(x))),key=sum)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3vXISc5NSEhUqrHITKzQ0KqITrZJi0_KLFBIVMvMUihLz0lM1clLzNCo0NUGiSRiimjrZqZW2xaW5mlATVQuKMvNKNNI0og11jHSMdXSNdQxiNTW54MK6hkAuRPGCBRAaAA)

Comment: As per OP's "Create a function to determine the largest sum of any array's adjacent subarrays.", you should return the largest sum, not the subarray.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 9 bytes

Anonymous tacit prefix function.

```apl
⌈/∘∊⍋+/¨⊂
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1FPh/6jjhmPOroe9XZr6x9a8air6X/ao7YJj3r7HnU1P@pd86h3y6H1xo/aJj7qmxoc5AwkQzw8g4Fq@qZ6Bfv7qUfrGukoGOoo6BrrKJgAKSATKmAKFIhVBwA)

`⊂` on the entire input:

`+/¨` sum sub-sequences of each of the following lengths:

`⍋` the grade (permutation that would sort, but the order doesn't matter; we just need all the indices as lengths)

`∘∊` **e**nlist (flatten), and then:

`⌈/` find the maximum (lit. maximum reduction)

---

For reference, Kadane's algorithm can be [found on APLcart](https://aplcart.info?q=kadane), but is much longer:

```apl
{s←0 ⋄ ⌈/{s⊢←0⌈s+⍵}¨⍵}
```

This sets the maximum sum with `s←0` then, for each element `{`…`}¨⍵` we update the sum `s⊢←` with the maximum of zero and `0⌈` the sum plus that element `s+⍵`. Finally, we find the maximum `⌈/`.

Comment: This is what I exactly wanted, splendid job! I definitely wanted to return an integer in output, and checked back that the output must be 6.

Comment: @AitzazImtiaz I've added Kadane's algorithm for reference.

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 3 bytes

```
►ΣQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9G0XecWB/7//z9a10jHUEfXWMdER9dQB8w21TGJBQA)

```
►       # maximum by
 Σ      # sum
        # of 
  Q     # all contiguous subarrays
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `G`, 9 bytes

```
Lʀ:Ẋƛ?$i∑
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJHIiwiIiwiTMqAOuG6isabPyRp4oiRIiwiIiwiWy0yLCAxLCAtMywgNCwgLTEsIDIsIDEsIC01LCA0XSJd)

##### Explanation

```python
Lʀ:Ẋƛ?$i∑  # Implicit input
Lʀ         # Length range
  :Ẋ       # Cartesian product with itself
    ƛ      # Map:
     ?$i   #  Slice input
        ∑  #  Sum
           # G flag gets maximum
```

Comment: As per OP's "Create a function to determine the largest sum of any array's adjacent subarrays.", you should return the largest sum, not the subarray.

Comment: @Adám fixed and saved 4 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 bytes

```
sᶠ+ᵐ⌉
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v/jhtgXaD7dOeNTT@f9/dLyRjoKhjkK8sY6CCZACMqECpkCB2P9RAA)

Please note that the negative symbol for negative numbers is the underscore `_` in Brachylog, not the standard dash `-`.

#### Explanation

```
sᶠ        Find all sublists of consecutive elements
  +ᵐ      Map sum
    ⌉     Get the max
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Because the required ouput is not clear from the spec, the first solution below outputs the sub-array, while the second outputs its sum.

```
ã ñx
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=4yDxeA&input=Wy0yLCAxLCAtMywgNCwgLTEsIDIsIDEsIC01LCA0XQ)

```
ãx Í
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=43ggzQ&input=Wy0yLCAxLCAtMywgNCwgLTEsIDIsIDEsIC01LCA0XQ)

```
ã ñx     :Implicit input of array
ã        :Sub-arrays
  ñ      :Sort by
   x     :  Sum
         :Implicit output of last element
```

```
ãx Í     :Implicit input of array
ã        :Sub-arrays
 x       :Reduced by addition
   Í     :Sort
         :Implicit output of last element
```

Comment: Actually the question states to find the sum, not the subarray. So this would be `ãx ñ`

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, <s>70</s> 74 bytes

```
=LET(b,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1#)),MAX(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(A1#,b-1,,TRANSPOSE(b)))))
```

where `A1#` is a *vertical* spill range comprising the values from the array.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot assume a named range for input in worksheet based languages [(meta link)](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14421/61846). The best way to take array inputs is to use the [Spilled Range Operator (#)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/spilled-range-operator-3dd5899f-bca2-4b9d-a172-3eae9ac22efd) and assume that the array begins at cell `A1`, ie take input from `A1#`

Comment: @TaylorAlexRaine Thanks, will amend. Before I do so, however, could you just clarify why referencing a spilled range *is* permissible? Based on the criteria you give in a comment in the linked post - "*1 - it requires user action that is neither self explanatory to someone who does not know these languages nor standardized, which leads to confusion in implementation and 2 - It corresponds to a distinct programmable action that you are bypassing without contributing anything to the bytecount*", I would've thought that the use of a spilled range would fail at least point 1, if not also point 2.

Comment: Jos, this just comes down to [what the community considers standard I/O for each language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/61846), both at the program and function level. For more traditional languages this is pretty cut and dry - STDIN/STDOUT, files for programs, and passed variables for functions. But Excel, well is odd. When we decided the standards, lambda functions and dynamic arrays did not exist - there was no concept of a passed variable, only referenced ranges (1/5)

Comment: Named ranges were initially used by some users to reduce their bytecounts, but this soon led to issues. One that was common was using ranges to refer to multiple areas (ie named range `a` referring to `A1:C3,D4:F6`). This negated the challenge of several otherwise fun problems and was eventually deemed to be against the spirit of codegolf. There were two key arguements for banning this - 1. assuming that input was taken by a predefined variable was already disallowed in almost all other languages; and - 2. it corresponded programmable actions being manually bypassed by the user. (2/5)

Comment: By contrast, taking input from a cell is canonical to Excel, present in its current form (albeit with R1C1 addresses) as far back as Microsoft Multiplan circa 1982. This is the standard I/O upon which the language is built. And the use of the the *`#` operator* only builds on this. Microsoft added the this operator in 2019 to allow you to pass entire arrays into aggregating functions like `sum` and `mean`. (3/5)

Comment: The `#` operator simply passes the whole array definition- the data for which is stored internally in the top left cell of the array - into the aggregating function. That is, it is a unary postfix operator that takes a array defining cell, and returns the whole legacy CSE array definition (added in '95 {? - documentation is slim}; like `{=LinEst(...)}`) or dynamic array definition (added in '19; like `={1,2;3,4}`) that is defined within that cell. (4/5)

Comment: Honestly the default behavior is kinda wierder - as if you reference a cell that defines an array and do not include `#`, Excel assumes that it needs to intercept and step into that array, rather than just return the whole object. This would be kinda like if the pseudocode `DIM X as Variant; X=Array(1,2,3,4)` followed by `print x` returned `>1`, but `print x#` returned `>[1, 2, 3, 4]`. I hope that helps to answer some of your questions about why Excel's I/O is so odd (5/5)

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation, Taylor. Much appreciated. It does indeed seem like Excel presents anything but a cut and dry case! And you've obviously put many hours of thought and discussion into this. One last thing re Named Ranges: although, as you say, "*It is invalid to assume that the user has manually redefined a given range to a shorter name*", is it nevertheless permissible to use a Named Range in your answer, providing it is declared as part of the byte count? (1/2)

Comment: By that, I mean not necessarily programmatically, as in your example (`ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add"A","=A1"`), but simply as per [this recent answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/257298/116680)? (2/2)

Comment: @TaylorAlexRaine So they see this comment. I'm not familiar with excel, but see no reason that wouldn't be allowed. Regardless, you still need to edit your answer to not use a named range.

Comment: @TheFifthMarshal Done.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 42 bytes

```
a=>a.map(s=m=n=>m=m>(s=0<s?n+s:n)?m:s)|m
```

Try it:

```js
f=a=>a.map(s=m=n=>m=m>(s=0<s?n+s:n)?m:s)|m

;[
  [-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4], // 6
  [1], // 1
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], // 28
  [-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7], // -1
  [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3], // 6
].map(a=>console.log(f(a)))
```

### UPD 45 -> 42

Thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld) for the [tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/257808/find-the-largest-sum-of-any-contiguous-subarray-of-the-array/257814?noredirect=1#comment569763_257814) to reduce bytes count

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 65 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,x=0,y=0:max(x-y,len(a)and f(a[1:],x:=x+a[0],min(x,y)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYpBCsMgEAC/sseVrGCSForgS8TDllQaiFsJOayvNx56mmGY2q7vT9ZXPXvP4eDy3hiYNDhqwfnCimobHR9BNiwbZOQ4@0Tqg04cXaKyCyo1Y0yv5y4XZox2IZgJ7ErwGBj6D88R0jhv)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 24 bytes

```
Max[Tr/@Subsequences@#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773zexIjqkSN8huDSpOLWwNDUvObXYQTlW7X9AUWZeiUO6g0K1rpGOgqGOgq6xjoIJkAIyoQKmQIHa//8B)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 41 bytes

Like several other answers, this assumes that the empty array is a valid subarray.

```javascript
a=>Math.max(...a.map(v=>s=v>-s&&s+v,s=0))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1s43sSRDLzexQkNPTy8RyCjQKLO1K7Yts9MtVlMr1i7TKbY10NT8n5yfV5yfk6qXk5@ukaYRrWuko2Coo6BrrKNgAqSATKiAKVAgFqgeAA)

Comment: Gives 0 if all numbers are negative integers but must give the biggest negative integer

Comment: @EzioMercer Why should it? Considering that we can select an empty subarray with sum 0 is just as sensible. The OP must clarify that point but has not yet answered tsh's question in the comments.

Comment: Why this depend on empty array? `[-1, -2, -3]` - in this example the biggest sum is `-1` how it can be a `0`? I agree that an empty array is an edge case of the problem, but if we have elements it can't be anything but the largest sum of elements

Comment: @EzioMercer What I mean is that a subarray of length 0 can be extracted from any input array, leading to a sum of 0.

Comment: I got your point :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 41 bytes

```python
lambda a,x=0:max(x:=max(c+x,0)for c in a)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3NXMSc5NSEhUSdSpsDaxyEys0KqxsQVSydoWOgWZafpFCskJmnkKiJlSDf0FRZl6JRppGtKGOkY6xjq6xjkGspiYXXFjXSEfBUEcBKK5gAqSATKiAKVAAVaUhkAsxdsECCA0A)

Version that can handle empty input:

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 43 bytes

```python
lambda a,x=0:max(x:=c+x*(x>0)for c in[0]+a)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3tXMSc5NSEhUSdSpsDaxyEys0Kqxsk7UrtDQq7Aw00_KLFJIVMvOiDWK1EzWhWmIKijLzSjTSNKINdYx0jHV0jXUMYjU1ueDCukY6CoY6CkBxBRMgBWRCBUyBAqgqDVG4QA7EjgULIDQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ŒOZ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6CT/qP//o410FAx1FHSNdRRMgBSQCRUwBQrEAgA)

TIL that there's a "sublists" command in both 05AB1E and Vyxal!

```python
Œ   # Sublists
 O  # Sum each
  Z # Maximum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>46</s> 45 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to pajonk*

```r
\(s){b=0;for(x in s)b=max(F<-max(x,F+x),b);b}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMHG3MSK-OLSpMSiosRKICPXdmlpSZquxU3dGI1izeokWwPrtPwijQqFzDyFYs0kW6ByDTcbXRBVoeOmXaGpk6RpnVQL1WSEbppGsoaukY6CoY6CrrGOggmQAjKhAqZAAU1NiM4FCyA0AA)

Outputs the sum of the subarray with the largest sum (as requested in the second sentence of the question)

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 59 bytes

```r
\(s,`+`=sum,b={}){for(x in s)if(+(F=c(F[+F>0],x))>+b)b=F;b}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMHG3MSK-OLSpMSiosRKICPXdmlpSZquxU3rGI1inQTtBFugmE6SbXWtZnVafpFGhUJmnkKxZmaahraGm22yhlu0tpudQaxOhaamnXaSZpKtm3VSLdQII3SzNZI1dI10FAx1FHSNdRRMgBSQCRUwBQpoakJ0LlgAoQE)

Outputs the subarray with the largest sum (as in the example in the third sentence of the question).

Comment: Removing one lost pair of parens in the first one results in [-1](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMHG3MSK-OLSpMSiosRKICPXdmlpSZquxU3dGI1izeokWwPrtPwijQqFzDyFYs0kW6ByDTcbXRBVoeOmXaGpk6RpnVQL1WSEbppGsoaukY6CoY6CrrGOggmQAjKhAqZAAU1NiM4FCyA0AA).

Comment: @pajonk - how did I miss that?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 6 bytes

```
eSsM.:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PzW42FfP6v//aF0jHQVDHQVdYx0FEyAFZEIFTIECsQA)

#### Explanation

```
eSsM.:Q    # implicitly add Q
           # implicitly assign Q = eval(input())
    .:Q    # list all subarrays of Q
  sM       # map to their sums
eS         # sort and take the last value (the largest sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 48 bytes

```
00i:?v/::0$0)?$~-{20.
+i}-1/\&~$?(@:$@:&:
 ;n~~/
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiMDBpOj92Lzo6MCQwKT8kfi17MjAuXG4raX0tMS9cXCZ+JD8oQDokQDomOlxuIDtufn4vIiwiaW5wdXQiOiI3IDEgLTIgMSAyIDMgLTMgMiIsInN0YWNrIjoiIiwic3RhY2tfZm9ybWF0IjoibnVtYmVycyIsImlucHV0X2Zvcm1hdCI6Im51bWJlcnMifQ==)

I thought Kadane's algorithm would always be longer but for ><>, which lacks normal array manipulation, it's actually shorter.

Takes input as a length-prefixed array.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 14 bytes

```
Ｉ⌈Ｅθ⌈Ｅθ↨¹✂θκ⊕μ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzexIjO3NBdIF2gU6iigcZ0Si1M1DHUUgnMyk1NBAtk6Cp55yUWpual5JakpGrmaMGD9/390tK6RjgJQta6xjoIJkAIyoQKmQIHY2P@6ZTkA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
   θ            Input array
  Ｅ             Map over elements
      θ         Input array
     Ｅ          Map over elements
         ✂θκ⊕μ  Inclusive slice of elements
       ↨¹       Take the sum
    ⌈           Take the maximum
 ⌈              Take the maximum
Ｉ               Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```

(Using "base 1" to take the sum as that returns `0` for empty lists.)